# Cannot feed value on Stateful LSTM keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

What's the problem with the code?

It returns `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 5, 7) for Tensor u'lstm_1_input:0', which has shape '(5, 5, 7)'` error.

My Code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,batch_input_shape=(5,5,7),return_sequences=True,stateful=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./model28-{epoch:02d}.h5')
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(trainX,trainY,batch_size=5,epochs=20,validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[checkpoint],shuffle=False)
```

Comment: What's your trainX look like? The error is saying that you said the input shape is (5,5,7) but you're trying to feed it a (2,5,7) tensor which it can't accept.

Comment: My trainX shape is `(34365, 5, 7)`

Comment: Can you not just change the input shape to (2,5,7)?

Comment: @MennoVanDijk  `34365` can't be devided by `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `trainX` shape was  34365. I remove 5 last row to have shape of 34360(shape should be devided by `batch_size`).
Each `epoch`, `reset_states()` should be called so I changed my code to this:

```
epo_num= 20
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,batch_input_shape=(2,5,7),return_sequences=False,stateful=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
#checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./model30-{epoch:02d}.h5')
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
for i in range(epo_num):
    print('Epochs {:d}/{:d}'.format(i+1,epo_num))
    model.fit(trainX,trainY,batch_size=2,epochs=1,validation_split=0.2,shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```